# How can I make my javascript code permanent?

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, local-storage

There are a light theme and a dark theme button in the design. I want the user to automatically load the last chosen theme the next time they enter the site. How can I do it?

My javascript code:

```
  $(".mode").on("click", function () {
    $('.mode i').toggleClass("fa-moon-o").toggleClass("fa-lightbulb-o");
    $('body').toggleClass("dark-only");
});
```

Comment: How about just using system preference prefer-color? anyway store there choise in LocalStorage, SessionStorage, IndexedDB, Cookie or user preferences on the backend, if it occurs add the class dark-only

Comment: Use `localStorage` and check it always when document is ready.
You can make `localStorage.setItem("dark-mode", "yes")` then make `$( document ).ready(function() {
    if(localStorage.getItem("dark-mode") == "yes") // set your dark mode classess
});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can save it in the localStorage and retrieve it when you load the side.

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage